# Creating one chapter from multiple Rmd files & order of knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

What is the best way, to combine multiple Rmd files into one chapter? e.g in the given example:

```
# Applications

Some _significant_ applications are demonstrated in this chapter.

## Example one

## Example two
```

I would like `Example one` and `Example two` to come from separate Rmd files. However, I cannot find a way to do this. What commands could be used?

Also, how the order of the chapters are determined during building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [usage](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html) section of the `bookdown` documentation. By default, files are merged by order of their filenames. So You could use something like.

- `03_Applications.Rmd`:

  ```
  # Applications

  Some _significant_ applications are demonstrated in this chapter.
  ```
- `03_1_Example_one.Rmd`:

  ```
  ## Example one
  ...
  ```
- `03_2_Example_two.Rmd`:

  ```
  ## Example two
  ...
  ```

(Assuming that "Applications" is the third chapter.)

If you want the freedom to rearrange chapters without renaming them, you can use the `rmd_files: [...]` YAML header. See the [usage](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html) section of the `bookdown` documentation for details.